# C++ Casting between template invocations

Tags: c++, templates, casting

suppose `X<T>` is a template class taking a class as parameter and `A` and `B` are classes with `B` being derived from `A` without involvement of multiple or virtual inheritance (i.e. no pointer adjustments necessary when casting between `A` and `B`).

is it safe to perform a chainsaw reinterpret cast from `X<A*>` to `X<B*>` or vice versa? Of course, a `X<A*>` is no `X<B*>`, but shouldn't these classes always share the same behaviour? Because pointers are used, the memory layout should be equal. Thus, it might be okay to let methods of `X<B*>` operate on an instance which is actually an `X<A*>`.

Of course, this somehow ruins type safety as I could for example insert an element of `A*` into an `X<B*>`, but this is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: In general, no. `reinterpret_cast` is not terribly useful.

Comment: why? Where will the code break?

Comment: Just write a templated conversion operator instead.

Comment: @gexicide Somewhere. I haven't seen any code yet.

Comment: well the code would be something like X<B*> b = reinterpret_cast<X<B*>>(new X<A*>());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to write something like this, if you REALLY need it.

```
X<A*> a(new B());
X<B*> b( dynamic_cast<B*> ( a.get_pointer() ) );
if(b.get_pointer() != NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: but what if the class maintains a large collection of A*s. I cannot just get a single pointer, I must copy all content.

Comment: Then I'll repeat R. Martinho Fernanes and Pubby. Don't do this. It is very dirty hack (like goto, for example).

Comment: I think my question is posed bad, because I left out the intention behind it. I do not want to write such code, I just want to generate it, so dirty hacks in the generated code are okay, as long as their behaviour is fine. I have reposted the question with better explanation, you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912786/compiling-java-generics-with-wildcards-to-c-templates

Comment: It’s not like `goto`. While I intensely dislike `goto` because it wreaks havoc with code structure (and I never use it), it’s completely *safe* to use. The `reinterpret_cast`, on the other hand, is *not* safe since the C++ standard gives *no* guarantees about this behaviour. Whether it works or not is a matter of pure chance.

Comment: Look into the side of boost::any. This will be much better. In Java you're also boxing and unboxing varaibles in the Object type. And this also needs casting operators.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. If B is of a polymorphic class casting B* to A* might change the value of the pointer. Generally speaking using reinterpret_cast is never safe, and if still you need it, then you probably wrote something wrong (There are some cases, where you need to you it, but this isn't one of them).

And by the way, templates can be specialized on template parameters, so X and X might not even have the same internal structure.