# Compiling Java Generics with Wildcards to C++ Templates

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics, compiler-construction

I am trying to build a Java to C++ trans-compiler (i.e. Java code goes in, semantically "equivalent" (more or less) C++ code comes out).

Not considering garbage collection, the languages are quite familiar, so the overall process works quite well already. One issue, however, are generics which do not exist in C++. Of course, the easiest way would be to perform erasure as done by the java compiler. However, the resulting C++ code should be nice to handle, so it would be good if I would not lose generic type information, i.e., it would be good, if the C++ code would still work with `List<X>` instead of `List`. Otherwise, the C++ code would need explicit casting everywhere where such generics are used. This is bug-prone and inconvenient.

So, I am trying to find a way to somehow get a better representation for generics. Of course, templates seem to be a good candidate. Although they are something completely different (metaprogramming vs. compile-time only type enhancement), they could still be useful. As long as no wildcards are used, just compiling a generic class to a template works reasonably well. However, as soon as wildcards come into play, things get really messy.

For example, consider the following java constructor of a list:

```
class List<T>{
List(Collection<? extends T> c){
    this.addAll(c);
}
}

//Usage
Collection<String> c = ...; 
List<Object> l = new List<Object>(c);
```

how to compile this? I had the idea of using chainsaw reinterpret cast between templates. Then, the upper example could be compiled like that:

```
template<class T>
class List{
List(Collection<T*> c){
    this.addAll(c);
}
}

//Usage
Collection<String*> c = ...; 
List<Object*> l = new List<Object*>(reinterpret_cast<Collection<Object*>>(c));
```

however, the question is whether this reinterpret cast produces the expected behaviour. Of course, it is dirty. But will it work? Usually, `List<Object*>` and `List<String*>` should have the same memory layout, as their template parameter is only a pointer. But is this guaranteed?

Another solution I thought of would be replacing methods using wildcards by template methods which instanciate each wildcard parameter, i.e., compile the constructor to

```
template<class T>
class List{

template<class S>
List(Collection<S*> c){
    this.addAll(c);
}
}
```

of course, all other methods involving wildcards, like `addAll` would then also need template parameters. Another problem with this approach would be handling wildcards in class fields for example. I cannot use templates here.

A third approach would be a hybrid one: A generic class is compiled to a template class (call it `T<X>`) and an erased class (call it `E`). The template class `T<X>` inherits from the erased class `E` so it is always possible to drop genericity by upcasting to E. Then, all methods containing wildcards would be compiled using the erased type while others could retain the full template type.

What do you think about these methods? Where do you see the dis-/advantages of them?
Do you have any other thoughts of how wildcards could be implemented as clean as possible while keeping as much generic information in the code as possible?

Comment: *" Although they are something completely different (metaprogramming vs. compile-time only type enhancement),"* C++ templates provide both.

Comment: Whether it works or not depends on the implementation of `Collection`. If it has any virtual functions, which, being translated from Java, I suspect it has, this has undefined behaviour (and this should not be taken to imply that if there are no virtual functions it is fine). As I mentioned in another question `reinterpret_cast` is not terribly useful.

Comment: why? Of course, it has virtual methods. However, calling a method of `Collection<Object*>` onto an object which is actually a `Collection<String*>` should be fine if they share the same memory layout.

Comment: First, because the result of the `reinterpret_cast` is unspecified. Second, because it causes violations of the aliasing rules, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the goal is to represent Java semantics in C++, then do so in the most direct way. Do not use `reinterpret_cast` as its purpose is to *defeat* the native semantics of C++. (And doing so between high-level types almost always results in a program that is allowed to crash.)

You should be using reference counting, or a similar mechanism such as a custom garbage collector (although that sounds unlikely under the circumstances). So these objects will all go to the heap anyway.

Put the generic `List` object on the heap, and use a separate class to access that as a `List<String>` or whatever. This way, the persistent object has the generic type that can handle any ill-formed means of accessing it that Java can express. The accessor class contains just a pointer, which you already have for reference counting (i.e. it subclasses the "native" reference, not an Object for the heap), and exposes the appropriately downcasted interface. You might even be able to generate the template for the accessor using the generics source code. If you *really* want to try.

Comment: You're probably right. My answer tries to salvage that the underlying C++ collection knows the type, but I suspect that after a certain amount of development I'd find some edge case of "ill-formed access that Java can express", give up, and switch to what you say -- enforce the type only in the wrappers, and the "real" collection is always of `Object*`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Regarding ill-formed access... you can, for example, create a Java function that takes a generic List, pass it a List< int >, and within the function, add a String to the List... ?:-)

Comment: @DevSolar: yes, there's going to be a `dynamic_cast` in there somewhere, for normal usage. But if Java gives you the means to bypass the checks completely, and successfully add a `String` to a collection object that was created as `ArrayList<int>`, then of course the underlying C++ container must be of `Object` just like the Java one is. There's no way around it.

Comment: Yes, this answer seems reasonable (together with the previous from Steve). I do use reference counting already, so it would nicely fit in there. Also the idea of creating covariant and contravariant views of generic classes and only passing these to methods with co or contravariant wildcards sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Good luck… I'm no expert in Java but from my initial read-up on generics, you are allowed to do things like get a completely dynamic type at runtime and bind it to an unparameterized (terminology?) container. Such hackery won't work with any use of C++ templates at all… but you might not be interested in supporting *all* Java code. Or I don't know, maybe the semantics of actually using such a container are restrictive enough that you can test `typeid` at some critical point, and either throw an exception or proceed with a static type and no loss of functionality. Maybe. Else things get hairy.

Comment: yes, I maintain a typeid at runtime, so I can perform a runtime check of type parameters when someone tries to downcast for example, from Object to List<String>. And yes, I do not support all the nonsense of java generics, especially not the ones that make the complete type system unsound.

Answer (score 6):

> Not considering garbage collection, the languages are quite familiar, so the overall process works quite well already.

No. While the two languages actually *look* rather similar, they are *significantly* different as to "how things are done". Such 1:1 trans-compilations as you are attempting will result in terrible, underperforming, and most likely faulty C++ code, *especially* if you are looking not at a stand-alone application, but at something that might interface with "normal", manually-written C++.

C++ requires a completely different programming *style* from Java. This begins with *not* having all types derive from `Object`, touches on avoiding `new` unless absolutely necessary (and then restricting it to constructors as much as possible, with the corresponding `delete` in the destructor - or better yet, follow Potatoswatter's advice below), and doesn't end at "patterns" like making your containers STL-compliant and passing `begin`- and `end`-iterators to another container's constructor instead of the whole container. I also didn't see const-correctness or pass-by-reference semantics in your code.

Note how many of the early Java "benchmarks" claimed that Java was faster than C++, because Java evangelists took Java code and translated it to C++ 1:1, just like you are planning to do. There is nothing to be won by such transcompilation.

Comment: I was sure that such an answer would be posted... I am more familiar with C++ as the code might look like. Of course, I start with producing running code rather than clean, elegant, high performance code. It is much harder to make a program write good C++ than writing it myself. I know about all the problems that you have posted, I have dealt with them and they are out of the scope of this question. Of course, the generated code will not look like natively written C++ code and will not use STL compliant containers. This is not the point here.

Comment: @gexicide: It's at the *core* of the problem. If you had "dealt" with "all the problems", you wouldn't *have* this particular one. I'm not talking about "lcean, elegant, high performance" code. I'm talking about *meaningful* code, something that serves a purpose beyond "it can be done, *technically*". If you disagree, just ignore this answer.

Comment: +1, but `new` is harder to make exception-safe than simply putting a `delete` in the destructor. It's best to use smart pointer and container classes for everything.

Comment: The question was not about whether it is a good idea to write a Java to C++ compiler but about this specific issue. And where do you see an condescending undertone about C++'s capabilities in my text?

Comment: @gexicide What is your goal? Unless this is purely for practice in translating between language semantics, it's a waste of time. You need to use a real Java JIT with a real native interface.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's been years since I last wrote a "new", so you're probably right. ;-)

Comment: @gexicide: "Generics do not exist in C++"? Templates being "something completely different (metaprogramming vs. compile-time only type enhancement)", but "they could still be useful"?

Comment: different is not worse. And (Java) generics do not exist in C++, that is a fact. I regard templates, i.e., metaprogramming, as feature which is a lot mightier than (Java) generics, and it is indeed. "Still be useful" means "still useful for my application although they are something different". I see the power of C++'s features, they are just not applicable to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 5):

An approach you haven't discussed is to handle generic wildcards with a wrapper class template. So, when you see `Collection<? extends T>`, you replace it with an instantiation of your template that exposes a read-only[*] interface like `Collection<T>` but wraps an instance of `Collection<?>`. Then you do your type erasure in this wrapper (and others like it), which means the resulting C++ is reasonably nice to handle.

Your chainsaw `reinterpret_cast` is *not* guaranteed to work. For instance if there's multiple inheritance in `String`, then it's not even possible in general to type-pun a `String*` as an `Object*`, because the conversion from `String*` to `Object*` might involve applying an offset to the address (more than that, with virtual base classes)[**]. I expect you'll use multiple inheritance in your C++-from-Java code, for interfaces. OK, so they'll have no data members, but they will have virtual functions, and C++ makes no special allowance for what you want. I think with standard-layout classes you could probably reinterpret the pointers themselves, but (a) that's too strong a condition for you, and (b) it still doesn't mean you can reinterpret the collection.

[*] Or whatever. I forget the details of how the wildcards work in Java, but whatever's supposed to happen when you try to add a `T` to a `List<? extends T>`, and the `T` turns out not to be an instance of `?`, do that :-) The tricky part is auto-generating the wrapper for any given generic class or interface.

[**] And because strict aliasing forbids it.